# Mapping with Dapper cascading objects

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm refactoring an old query made with EF that's taking so much time.
I was wondering with Dapper if I can automatically map such objects

```
public class Chest
{
  public Item Item {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
   public IList<Property> Properties {get;set;}
}

public class Property
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way I can retrieve all those items as I would do with EF?

I've seen the Query and so on but I don't understand if it meets the case

Comment: `SplitOn` shall help in this case, actually you can do without it, this is simple mapping

Comment: `I'm refactoring an old query made with EF that's taking so much time` <= Before you throw a new framework at it I would try to figure out **why** it was taking too much time. It might be a trivial fix in the Lamda or possibly a missing index in the schema.

Comment: Can you post your query , that you are trying to use

Answer (score 1):

Your model is pretty straight forward, since there's only 1 collection - `IList<Property>`, let's assume your query is `Select Id, Description from PropertyTable`, then using Dapper, you can do the following:

```
IList<Property> PropertyList = conn.Query<Property>("Select Id, Description from PropertyTable").ToList();
```

After that its simple assignment:

```
Chest chest = new Chest{Item = new Item{Properties = PropertyList}};
```

This still need extra assignment, since from Dapper you get `IEnumerable<T>` as result, there could be a `Dapper Extension`, which can directly fill the `Chest` object, if you provide explicit object mapping, though in my view its not required, since the solution is simple

Comment: Even still as i mentioned what you can achieve is fetching `IEnumerable<T> ` from Dapper then explicit mapping. You might want to explore `SplitOn`, which can help in providing the one level of Child list inside a Parent object. However out here you don't have the Child list inside a Parent object

Comment: ok, this is reasonable but consider the case I've some nested properties, I have to perform such query one behind the other? (and I think it's what EF does under the hood)

Comment: EF can do things under the hood, but would have a toll on the overall performance. EF and Dapper have very different design philosophy, where Dapper is designed for the performance, it prefers to give bare metal `IEnumerable<T>`, which can be merged in the memory using Linq to Objects. At most it will provide 1 level of nested collection. For Dapper you can run various queries in Async mode and aggregate the data. On other hand EF will generate queries and create sub queries, but challenge is auto generation will make things slow and inefficient in few cases.

Comment: If you post the use case / requirement, it will be easy to provide a solution based on Dapper APIs, which is performance oriented